# Material Table not displaying any data

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm trying to get data from the backend API and map it to the table but no data is appearing. If I console data I can see the data I need in an array. I would appreciate any help, I'm new to React pardon me. Cheers.......................................................................

```
import { getAllCustomers } from "../../../../features/customers/customerSlice";
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const fetchInfo = () => {
    dispatch(getAllCustomers());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInfo();
  }, [setData]);
  console.log(data);
  

  const columns = [
    { title: "ID", field: "id" },
    { title: "Username", field: "username" },
    { title: "Name", field: "name" },
    { title: "Email", field: "email" },
    { title: "Phone", field: "phone" },
    { title: "Web Link", field: 'website' }
  ]

return (
      <CardBody>
      <ThemeProvider theme={defaultMaterialTheme}>
      <MaterialTable
      title="Employee Data"
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
    />
    </ThemeProvider>
      </CardBody>
  );
};

export default Customers;
```

customerSlice.jsx

```js
const initialState = {
  customer: [],
  autoCustomer: [],
  customers: [],
  isLoading: false,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  message: "",
};

// Get all customers
export const getAllCustomers = createAsyncThunk(
  "customer/getAllCustomers",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await customerService.getAllCustomers(token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

    
customerService.jsx
```

```js
const getAllCustomers = async (token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };
  const response = await axios.get(
    "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/customer/paginate-customer",
    config
  );
  return response.data;
};
```

I'd appreciate any tips. :)

Answer (score 0):

in your code, setData is never called, so data state is always [] (the init value you gave it)

If getAllCustomers returns an array of customers, maybe this should be more appropriate:

```js
// if getAllCustomers is not async
useEffect(() => {
    setData(getAllCustomers())
}, []);

// or getAllCustomers is async
useEffect(() => {
    getAllCustomers()
        .then((myData) => setData(myData))
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}, []);
```

Also, your use of useEffect is uneffective, setData should not be in the dependancies array since it will not change. More information on hooks here: https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: I get a 'dispatch is not a function error' for the first solution and 'getAllCustomers(...).then is not a function' for the second solution

Comment: What is the content of your getAllCustomers function ?

Comment: Just posted a snippet of the customerService and customerSlice

Comment: I, createAsyncThunk belongs to redux,I don't know this, sorry. The second getAllCustomers function seems usable with the example I gave you however.

Answer (score 0):

remove dependencies that you mention inside useEffect and that depedencies is is function remove [] empty can work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).